# Loading all .php files from a folder

Tags: php, file, ftp, root

I'm using a function to load all files in a folder which seems like:

```
foreach (glob(ROOT ."path/*.app.php") as $file) { 
    $filename = basename($file, '.app.php');
    load_app($filename);
}
```

Now, I thought that this could be a little bit insecure, and I'm pretty sure I read something about this being evil. But thinking about it I end up thinking that if someone can add a file to my root folder accessing it with FTP, then my problems are far worse than just the adding of a file. Isn't it?

Why should I avoid this behavior? Are there any reasons to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inherent security problem with that. I would just avoid it for simplicity and vague performance concerns.

If someone were able to add new files in your root folder, they would very likely also be able to modify existing files. So it's as you say, you would have far worse problems in that case. (A fixed list of includeable files thus wouldn't help either way.)

It's btw. an approach I use for a PHP cron script, which runs through an `cron.d/` folder with enumerated scripts for execution. Your library include use case has a bit different purpose, but I can't honestly see any factual problems with that. (The performance thingy is likely not measurable.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you've given is exactly the one that makes this *insecure* : if a `.app.php` file is put in your folder *(be if by mistake, or because someone intentionally put it there)*, it'll be interpreted.

It would be *safer* to not include all files -- but only a fixed list, that correspond to files you know.

Comment: But if someone can access my folder could do much more than just add a file, isn't it right? If I could access the root folder of a website I would delete the entire folder or change the code rather than adding a file which is autoloaded.

Comment: Except you would notice if every was deleted -- would you notice an additional file if it doesn't cause any error ?

Comment: Well, let's consider that nobody can access the folder. What other risks would there be? PS: I would find harder to find some extra lines of code inside an already existing file rather than a file more.

Comment: if there is no risk of any file being added/deleted/modified, I don't see why your code would not be OK